# Cannot start bacula director via init service

Tags: debian, systemd

I have been trying to set up the bacula director on a debian 8 system and found that running the command `bacula-dir` starts the director correctly, but `service bacula-director start` does not. running `sudo service bacula-director status` after starting the service yeilds

```
● bacula-director.service - LSB: Start Bacula Director at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/bacula-director)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2017-05-15 22:12:00 PDT; 16min ago
  Process: 5614 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/bacula-director reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5418 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/bacula-director start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

May 15 22:12:00 debian-media systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Bacula Director at boot time...
May 15 22:12:00 debian-media bacula-director[5418]: Starting Bacula Director...: bacula-dir.
May 15 22:12:00 debian-media systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Bacula Director at boot time.
May 15 22:13:04 debian-media systemd[1]: Reloading LSB: Start Bacula Director at boot time.
May 15 22:13:04 debian-media bacula-director[5614]: Reloading Bacula Director...: bacula-dir
May 15 22:13:04 debian-media systemd[1]: Reloaded LSB: Start Bacula Director at boot time.
May 15 22:28:20 debian-media systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Bacula Director at boot time.
```

The `active (exited)` seems suspicious since the other bacula daemons are `active (running)`. Plus, the output of `ps -A` does not show a process for the director whereas with manually starting, it does.

The bacula director's service definition is an init script (which I find impenetrable) installed with the director via `apt-get`. Aside from perhaps making a systemd unit file to replace the init script, how can I start the director as a service?

bacula director's init script

```
#! /bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          bacula-director
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:      bacula-fd postgresql mysql
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Stop:       bacula-fd postgresql mysql
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start Bacula Director at boot time
# Description:       bacula-director is the daemon that supervises all the
#                    backup, restore, verify and archive operations. The
#                    system administrator uses the Bacula Director to schedule
#                    backups and to recover files.
### END INIT INFO
# bacula-director     SysV init script for Bacula-Director.
#
#       Written by Miquel van Smoorenburg <miquels@cistron.nl>.
#       Modified for Debian GNU/Linux by Ian Murdock <imurdock@gnu.ai.mit.edu>.
#       Customized for Bacula by Jose Luis Tallon <jltallon@adv-solutions.net>
#

set -e

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/bacula-dir
NAME="bacula-dir"
PORT=9101
DESC="Bacula Director"

if [ ! -x $DAEMON ] ; then
    echo "No bacula-director SQL package installed"
    exit 0
fi

if [ -n "`getent services bacula-dir`" ]; then
        PORT=`getent services bacula-dir | awk '{ gsub("/tcp","",$2); print $2; }'`
fi


PIDFILE=/var/run/bacula/$NAME.$PORT.pid

. /lib/lsb/init-functions
. /usr/share/bacula-common/common-functions.init
if [ -r /etc/default/$NAME ]; then
    . /etc/default/$NAME
fi

CONFIG="${CONFIG:-/etc/bacula/$NAME.conf}"

create_var_run_dir

get_pid()
{
    if [ -r "$1" ]; then pid="`cat $1`"; 
    else pid=""; fi
}

kill_pid()
{
    kill -$1 $2 2>/dev/null || true
}

# do_start()
do_start()
{
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE \
    --oknodo --exec $DAEMON -- -c $CONFIG $ARGS
}

# do_stop()
do_stop()
{
    start-stop-daemon --oknodo --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE \
        --retry TERM/30/KILL/5 --exec $DAEMON -- -c $CONFIG $ARGS
}


########################################################################

case "$1" in
  start)
    if [ "$ENABLED" = "no" ]; then
                log_failure_msg "Not starting $DESC: disabled via /etc/default/$NAME"
        exit 0
    fi

    create_var_run_dir
    log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC..." "$NAME"
        if do_start ; then
                log_end_msg 0
        else
                log_end_msg 1
        fi
  ;;

  stop)
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC..." "$NAME"
        if do_stop ; then
                log_end_msg 0
        else
                log_end_msg 1
        fi
  ;;

  reload)
        log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC..." "$NAME"
        get_pid $PIDFILE
        if [ -n "$pid" ]; then kill_pid HUP $pid ;
        else do_start ;
        fi
  ;;

  restart|force-reload)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
  ;;

  status)
       status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON $NAME
  ;;

  *)
    N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
    # echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload}" >&2
    echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: May be check your bacula configuration with `bacula-dir /etc/bacula/bacula-dir.conf -dt -f -t` ?

Comment: @MUYBelgium I'll emphasize again that the issue is not that Bacula does not work (It does, I had been using it for weekly backups for months when this question was posted). The issue is specifically with using Bacula as an init service (rather than starting it manually with bacula-dir and stopping it by finding its PID, which is what I had to do when I was still using Bacula (I stopped using it for reasons unrelated to the problem in this question))

Comment: This command does not start Bacula director, but test its configuration.  Just in case...

Comment: @MUYBelgium I know. I had tested the configuration before posting the question. And again, Bacula *does work when using that configuration*. The problem that I was having was incredibly specific to using the init script to start Bacula.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check db connection (see section catalog in config /etc/bacula/bacula-dir.conf)
2. Check you have installed pkgs bacula-director & bacula-director-pgsql

Comment: Could you describe these actions in a bit more detail, please?   (I.e., turn them into *descriptions* of *actions.*)   Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Yes to both. I'll emphasize again that the issue is not that bacula does not work (It does, I have been using it for weekly backups for months at this point). The issue is specifically with using bacula as a service (rather than starting it manually with bacula-dir and stopping it by finding its PID, which is what I currently have to do).